# Play 2.5.3/Ebean: NoSuchMethodError: com.avaje.ebean.config.ServerConfig.getConstraintNaming()

Tags: java, playframework, ebean, nosuchmethoderror

I'm using the Play 2.5.3 framework, and for whatever reason Ebean seems to be failing while creating evolutions for my local (in memory) database. Here's the full stack trace.

```
[info] play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[NoSuchMethodError: com.avaje.ebean.config.ServerConfig.getConstraintNaming()Lcom/avaje/ebean/config/DbConstraintNaming;]
[info]  at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:174)
[info]  at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:126)
[info]  at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
[info]  at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:126)
[info]  at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:124)
[info]  at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:231)
[info]  at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:124)
[info]  at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:116)
[info]  at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
[info]  at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
[info] Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.avaje.ebean.config.ServerConfig.getConstraintNaming()Lcom/avaje/ebean/config/DbConstraintNaming;
[info]  at com.avaje.ebean.dbmigration.model.CurrentModel.<init>(CurrentModel.java:37)
[info]  at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.generateEvolutionScript(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:91)
[info]  at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.lambda$create$4(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:59)
[info]  at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions$$Lambda$33/1642038057.accept(Unknown Source)
[info]  at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1280)
[info]  at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.create(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:58)
[info]  at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions.start(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:40)
[info]  at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions.<init>(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:150)
[info]  at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider.get$lzycompute(EvolutionsModule.scala:53)
[info]  at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider.get(EvolutionsModule.scala:53)
```

Googling this exception got me next to no information.

In my "application.conf" file,

```
ebean.default = ["models.*"]

    db {
      # You can declare as many datasources as you want.
      # By convention, the default datasource is named `default`

      # https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/Developing-with-the-H2-Database
      default.driver = org.h2.Driver
      default.url = "jdbc:h2:mem:play"
      default.username = sa
      default.password = ""

      # You can turn on SQL logging for any datasource
      # https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/Highlights25#Logging-SQL-statements
      #default.logSql=true
    }
```

which seems to be what everyone else uses. My ebean.properties file, which I thought also may be the problem, simply contains

```
ebean.namingconvention=com.avaje.ebean.config.MatchingNamingConvention
```

My build.sbt file looks as follows:

```
name := """Project-CS2340"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "webjars"    at "http://webjars.github.com/m2"
)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "org.webjars"               %% "webjars-play"       % "2.3.0",
  "org.webjars"               % "bootstrap"           % "3.0.0" exclude("org.webjars", "jquery"),
  "org.webjars"               % "jquery"              % "1.8.3",
  "org.avaje.ebeanorm" % "avaje-ebeanorm" % "4.6.2"
)

playEbeanDebugLevel := 4

fork in run := true
```

Earlier today, the application worked without error, and I suppose I changed something and forgot about it while taking a break. No idea, honestly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the library dependency of `ebean` in your build.sbt file

```
"org.avaje.ebeanorm" % "avaje-ebeanorm" % "4.6.2"
```

with the following

```
"org.avaje" % "ebean" % "2.7.3"
```

Have a good luck

Comment: Hey, unfortunately this didn't work. I changed that line and added the new .jar that was downloaded to the lib folder of my project. Got any other ideas? Thanks for the initial help!

Comment: I messed with my dependencies some more and got it to work. There seems to have been some issue with having multiple versions of ebean as a dependency. Getting rid of all of the ones except for ebean-2.7.3 and avaje-ebeanorm-6.18.1 and making the above changes to my build.sbt file fixed the problem.